# Не выводится внешний скрипт js

Tags: javascript

Создала файл `123.js` написала туда `alert(111);`

Почему не выводится `123.js` в следующем коде??

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
  $("#tab-title-tab3").click( function(){ 
    var script=document.createElement('script'); 
    script.src='123.js'; 
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script); 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: добавьте в вопрос разметку, а то я сейчас угадаю, в чем дело. А тут некоторых участников это расстраивает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ВОТ РАБОЧИЙ КОД:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    $("#tab-title-tab3").click( function(){ 
    var script=document.createElement('script'); 
    script.src='123.js'; 
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script); 
    ;}); 
    });
```